# Linking static library with -l flag

Tags: c, makefile, static

How can I have my makefile compile with the -l flag?

I have a makefile that looks like

```
myLibrary:
    gcc -c myLibrary.c -o myLibrary.o
    ar cr libmyLibrary.a myLibrary.o
```

and then I compile my main program with

```
main:
    gcc -g -c -o main.o main.c
    gcc main.o -o main libmyLibrary.a
```

The above makefile works, but if I want to replace

```
libmyLibrary.a
```

with `-lmyLibrary` I get an error. Shouldn't both be working the same?

Comment: You need to add -L option to set the directory where your library is to be found. The linker won't look for libraries specified with -l in the current directory. If all your build happens in one directory, `-L.` should work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a rudimentary, unrealistic makefile that will make the static library `libmyLibary`
before it makes the program `main`, which it will link with the static library
using the `-L` (library search-path) and `-l` (library) options.

**Makefile**

```
.PHONY: all clean

all: libmyLibrary.a main

main: main.o | libmyLibrary.a
    $(CC) -o main main.o -L. -lmyLibrary

libmyLibrary.a: myLibrary.o
    $(AR) rcs libmyLibrary.a myLibrary.o

clean:
    rm -f *.o libmyLibrary.a main
```

which runs like:

```
$ make
cc    -c -o myLibrary.o myLibrary.c
ar rcs libmyLibrary.a myLibrary.o
cc    -c -o main.o main.c
cc -o main main.o -L. -lmyLibrary
```

As I think you know, it's unrealistic to make both a library and a program
that links with it in the same makefile, since the point of a library is
that you don't need to keep remaking it to link it with many programs. You'd really have
a makefile for `libmyLibrary.a` and other makefiles for programs that
use it.

This is how the gcc linkage options `-L` and `-l` work:

```
-L/path/to/search
```

tells the linker to look for any libraries that you specify with the `-l` option in `/path/to/search`,
before it looks for them in its default search directories. The current directory, `.`,
isn't one of the linker's default search directories. So if you want it to
find a library specified with the `-l` option in the current directory, then you need to
specify `-L.`

```
-lfoo
```

tells the linker to search for either a dynamic library, `libfoo.so`, or a static
library, `libfoo.a`, first in your `-L` directories, if any, in the order you've
specified them, and then in its default search directories. It stops searching
as soon as if finds either `libfoo.so` or `libfoo.a` in one of the search directories.
If it finds *both* of them in the same directory, then by default it will link `libfoo.so` with
your program and not link `libfoo.a`.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to use -L but it wasn't working until I added the period after it

Answer (score 1):

To link purely statically library, use -static, Like

```
gcc -static main.c libmyLibrary.a
```

And run executable file `./a.out`  GCC Linux.

Comment: I am trying to avoid calling it with libmyLibrary.a I have to call it with the -l flag